# FormField value set with javascript, value lost on postback

Tags: 2010, jquery, custom-form, date-time, postback

I have a custom list of "requests" which need to accommodate a required time range for a single date (among other fields), so I added "start" and "end" columns of date and time type. I used designer to create a custom new form and displayed these two fields side by side. With jquery, I hid the textbox and calendar of the "end" field, so the user sees a single textbox and calendar for the date and two sets of time dropdown menus. Whenever the date is changed in the visible date textbox, I push it to the hidden date textbox with jquery.

When I click save, the form is validated and the hidden "end" date textbox loses its value. Why is the value lost and how can I keep it?

As a workaround, I'm sure I could make the "end" column not required and set its date within ItemAdding and ItemUpdating event receivers, but would prefer to resolve this on the client side if possible.

Comment: I'd get into firebug and see what all happens under the hood using a regular calendar control. Maybe jQuery is succesfully setting a form field value on the surface, but, the underlying viewstate gobbletygook isn't being notified of a field change in the same way as if a user had interacted with the control.

Comment: Yeah, I think my above comment is on the money. I've seen this before. It's all about the viewstate. Answer is going to be at another link found on this site:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1596330.aspx/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've disabled the EndDate element, it won't be saved. If thats the case, the trick is to re-enable it in the PreSaveAction().

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just leaving the EndDate element enabled since it is hidden. 

I think I would have to handle ALL validation myself in the PreSaveAction if I wanted that element to be visible and disabled. Right now, I let SP validate additional required fields and that seems to be called after the PreSaveAction(). So if any other fields fail their validation, the EndDate would remain enabled.